# How I get ajax response from controller in magento 2

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento2

I try to make an ajax call and pass the dropdown value in controller and get that particular related order information in view file. Response comes true but how to utilize that response in my view file.

**Here is my phtml file**:

```
<select id="chartOption">
   <option value="">Select Option</option>
   <option value="status">Status</option>
   <option value="payments">Payments</option>
   <option value="browser">Browser</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="chart_button" value="Generate chart" onclick="click_chart()">
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function click_chart() {
            var a = document.getElementById("chartOption");
            var abc = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
            data = jQuery(this).serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "Blog/Post/Information", 
                data: "label=" + abc,
                success: function (result) { jQuery('#result').html(result); },
                error: function (error) {  jQuery('#result').html(error); }
            });
        }
</script>
```

**And here is my controller:**

```
public function execute() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['ajax'])) {
        $label = $this->getRequest()->getPost('label');
        $_orders = $this->getOrders();
        $complete = $pending = $closed = $canceled = $processing = $onHold = 0;
        foreach ($_orders as $_order):
            $label = $_order->getStatusLabel();
            if ($label == 'Complete') {
                $complete++;
            }
            if ($label == 'Pending') {
                $pending++;
            }
            if ($label == 'Closed') {
                $closed++;
            }
            if ($label == 'Canceled') {
                $canceled++;
            }
            if ($label == 'Processing') {
                $processing++;
            }
            if ($label == 'On Hold') {
                $onHold++;
            }
        endforeach;
        $orderData = "['Task', 'Hours per Day'],['Complete'," . $complete . "],['Pending'," . $pending . "]],['Processing'," . $processing . "]],['Canceled'," . $canceled . "]";
        $arr = array('result' => $orderData);
        $jsonData = json_encode(array($arr));
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($jsonData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

below is the example how to do this, Please modify it according to your requirement.

I used js template for this.

Following example will create dropdown in your phtml file. you can use same method to display your data in the format you want.

In your JS

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'mage/template',
        'jquery/list-filter'
        ], function (
            $,
            _,
            template
        ) {
            function main(config, element) {
                var $element = $(element);
                $(document).on('click','yourID_Or_Class',function() {
                        var param = 'ajax=1';
                            $.ajax({
                                showLoader: true,
                                url: YOUR_URL_HERE,
                                data: param,
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: 'json'
                            }).done(function (data) {
                                $('#test').removeClass('hideme');
                                var html = template('#test', {posts:data}); 
                                $('#test').html(html);
                            });
                    });
            };
        return main;
    });
```

In Controller

```
public function __construct(
        Context                                             $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory    $resultJsonFactory,
    ) {
        
        $this->resultJsonFactory            = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $result                 = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) 
        {
            $test=Array
            (
                'Firstname' => 'What is your firstname',
                'Email' => 'What is your emailId',
                'Lastname' => 'What is your lastname',
                'Country' => 'Your Country'
            );
            return $result->setData($test);
        }
    }
```

IN your phtml file

```
<style>  
.hideme{display:none;}
</style>
<div id='test' class="hideme">
    <select>
    <% _.each(posts, function(text,value) { %>
        <option value="<%= value %>"><%= text %></option>
    <% }) %> 
    </select>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: this works but magento discourages the use of superglobals like $_REQUEST. if you want to submit to the marketplace it will be rejected.